# Generating fillable PDF as web form that can be submitted

Tags: c#, forms, pdf, itext

I am trying to generate a fillable PDF document that can be viewed in the web browser and filled up so after pushing a "Submit" button the data from the fields can be received on the server.

I am reading an article related with the iTextSharp but i still can not find a way of getting my mission accomplished. The example there is with a HTML form that after submitted the fields get binded to a pdf Template.

Is this my only option?

Comment: Using PDF forms to collect and gather data from users is a large topic. You probably want to read up on it and ask your question again when you understand pdf / Acrobat's built in capabilities. https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/form-submit-e-mail-demystified

Comment: Do you want to "see" the PDF on the server-side or just get the data? A PDF renderer can perform a standard HTTP POST with the values and server-side you can just process them as you normally would, no iText required. If you want the server-side to have the same PDFs as the client-side with the client's data filled in you have to perform some additional steps as Ollie pointed out but still iText shouldn't be required.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few online options.

- formsite - unlimited pdf generation for about $50, but you have to manually connect the fields.
- doculicious - automated creation of embed-able pdf form
- logiforms - same as formsite, but a little nicer and more options in other areas
- seamlessdocs - very nice email/web pdf automated  (still checking them out, but so far so good)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a fillable form, and then store the values when the user submits it, you might be better off with just an HTML form. A basic HTML form doesn’t require any extra tools, and won’t get PDF involved. This is the simplest solution to your question. If you need to use PDF, and have to provide the user with a copy of the filled out form, please clarify in the OP, and I can provide you with a mode detailed solution.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik It's possible to get the values via HTML form and then generate PDF's based on that. That would probably be much easier than getting the PDF to submit the data.